# How to solve the lexicon puzzle in the Skyrim Quest 'Discerning the Transmundane'?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I put the cube in the spot where it goes but nothing happened, my quest didn't change or update.

I have not found the elder school yet, but have used the sphere and now am putting the cube in its spot but nothing happens. Only 2 of the 5 buttons light up to activate, what haven't I done our am not doing right?

How do I solve the lexicon puzzle in the Skyrim Quest 'Discerning the Transmundane'?

Answer (score 5):

You have to press buttons in a certain order in order to complete the puzzle. There are answers to this question all over the web.

[GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/615804-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/answers/332747-how-do-i-solve-transcribe-lexicon-retreive-elder-scroll)

[Youtube](https://youtu.be/y9-MCF1tyHk?t=3m19s)

[Elderscrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Discerning_the_Transmundane) - This one is particularly useful as it lists possible bugs with the quest at the bottom.